# Display as > Wire in Eevee problem

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

In *Cycles*, if I enable the object's *Viewport Display > Display as > Wire* option, my object will be displayed as wire in *Solid* mode but as soon as I switch to *Rendered* mode it will be displayed as a normal solid object, as expected.

It allows for example, in *Solid* mode, to work on objects without being bothered by a big one, but the big one is back as soon as I switch to *Rendered* mode, which is good.

In *Eevee* though, if I enable the object's *Wire* option, the object will be displayed as wire in *Solid* mode as expected, but il will also be displayed as a wire in *Rendered* mode, which is not expected and is very annoying, as it requires to select it again, come back to *Display as*, and choose *Solid*. If I render an image the object will be normally displayed though, as expected.

Is there anything logical here? Am I missing something? Is there a way around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello :). This does seem weirdly inconsistent. The same thing also used to [happen in renders](https://developer.blender.org/T62564) but it was resolved. I'd ask the devs, this doesn't seem logical.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so yes you confirm that there's a problem here  :(